# problem in reading from firebase using firebaseDatabase.net in Xamarin and updating collection

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am making notes taking app, where you can store Notebooks, and inside those notebooks, you can have notes.

I am using Firebase and MVVM

Currently, I am facing two problems, that I have been stuck for days

The current flow of the app is like this

MainPage (NotebooksPage) -> NotePage

Is important to mention that you have PopUps, to create a Notebook or note

the first problem is that when you run the app for the first time and you create a new notebook, the collection will update, and you can use the new notebook on the screen, but if you navigate to a note and navigate back to the notebook's screen (MainPage) and you create a new notebook, you will not be able to see it even though is inserted in firebase

things I tried

1. Create an EventHandler that will trigger when the popup disappear
2. Call the read method when I close the pop-up
3. Create a Public method in the MainPageModel and call it when I create the notebook

The second problem is that when you navigate to the notes page, it will read the notebooks instead of the notebooks.
From them NotebooksPage (MainPage) I am passing the ID from the notebook I chose to the NotesPagee but for reasons that I don't understand, it will read my database twice, even though the child's name is in Notes and I m passing the notebook.

For example

I have this method

```
     public async void ReadAsync(string ChildName, string NotebookId = "") {

        var list = await Client.Child(ChildName)
             .OnceAsync<NotebookNote>();

        var collection = new List<NotebookNote>();

        foreach (var item in list) {
            NotebookNote notebookNote = null;
            notebookNote = Convert(ChildName, item);
            collection.Add(notebookNote);
        }

        if (ChildName.Equals(App.Notes)) {
            collection = collection.Where(n => ((Note)n).NotebookId == NotebookId).ToList();
        } else {
            collection = collection.Where(n => n.UserID == Preferences.Get(App.UserID, string.Empty)).ToList();
        }
        FireBaseNotebooks.Clear();
        foreach (var element in collection) {
            FireBaseNotebooks.Add(element);
        }

    }
```

The first time I read the method doesn't get an ID and I get all my notebooks, but when I navigate when I click on a notebook, and go to the notes page, I will read and the child name is note, so it should execute this

```
   if (ChildName.Equals(App.Notes)) {
            collection = collection.Where(n => ((Note)n).NotebookId == NotebookId).ToList();
```

I am reading one time on the notes page, so why is reading twice

If you could help me I would appreciate it

This is my project

https://github.com/eduardoagr/DuoNotes

Comment: you can try to use sqlite to store your notebooks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows

Comment: I do not want to use sqllite, because it is suppose to be an p that store in the cloud